# xcode running in emulator - issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I have a piece of software I wrote using xcode 5. Since I upgraded to xcode 6, the app looks strange when I run it on a physical device using the emulator. Not entirely sure what is going on or how I could fix it. It's not respecting the full size of the screen.

I am testing on an iPhone 5s (NOT simulator --  the app looks fine in the iPhone 5s simulator). I am connecting my phone to my comp and running it via xCode.

I am having the same issue with another project I built using xcode 5 and trying to run again in xcode 6...

thoughts anyone?!

Here is a screenshot of what is going on:

[image]

Comment: `Running on a physical device using the emulator`?! I have no idea what you are talking about. The simulator? What physical device It's really unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I am testing on an iPhone 5s. NOT the emulator. I am not using the actual simulator, but I am connecting my device to my computer and running it via xcode... Sorry if I was unclear. I didn't quite know how to say that. The app looks FINE in the actual iPhone 5s simulator.

Comment: Is you iPhone perhaps running iOS 7 and you've created a constraint based layout that has constraints from/to the baseline? This is a new feature in iOS 8 and these constraints break on iOS 7.

Comment: It is running iOS7... This makes sense. I will check it out, thanks for the tip!!

Comment: Is there a setting somewhere where I can revert this base to an iOS7 layout contraints? It seems to be affecting the whole app, not specific viewControllers... so that sort of seems like this would be an app configuration setting... I could be wrong.